# Should I take the TOEFL exam if I have graduated from a high school in the U.S.?

Tags: toefl, language-exams

I am currently a B.Tech. student in India, and am applying for Master's courses in the U.S. I took the GRE exam a week ago.

Does having graduated from high school in the U.S., where English is the native language, count as certification that my English is good enough? Should I still take the TOEFL exam?

Comment: If your previous level was in English, you normally do not need to sit any English test. But I insist you check the minimum admission requirements for the degree you are going to apply for, which is available on the website of the universities.

Comment: Do you mean *given*, as in you have given your grade to the applications committee, or do you actually mean *taken*, as in you recently sat the test?

Comment: @Moriarty I think this is a difference between American and British English, although in general I only hear Indians use "give and exam"

Comment: @StrongBad In my experience it's the same in both British and American English. The student *takes* the exam, the professor *gives* it - see a question about this on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58416/is-give-an-exam-grammatical-for-writing-the-answers-to-exam) . It looks to be a quirk in the way many Indians speak English (the OP's name is Sanskrit). I think that it's still *technically* correct, but the nuances of it just don't take on the correct meaning in the mind of a native speaker such as myself.

Comment: I know of a russian born guy that studied from high school in the USA. Some schools were demanding the TOEFL, but he was able to get it waived after a few phone calls.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you are applying as an international student, you need TOEFL. It does not depend on you high school education. For international students, you will be considered as a non-native english speaker, so toefl is necessary. If you are applying as a domestic student (meanign you have citizenship/greencard), you dont need toefl.

Anyways, toefl is a very easy exam!

Comment: I have never seen citizenship/greencard as a requirement. Based on this criteria people born and educated in English speaking countries like Canada would have to take the TOEFL, which again I have never heard of. Can you provide an example school that has a policy that requires a passport or greencard?

Comment: I mentioned greencard because the person who posted this q is from India and a non-native english speaker who did high school in us and bachelors in India. I did mention that in my reply. Non-native english speaker if he/she has gc or citizenship doesn't need TOEFL. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Diya Your meaning is clear, but *wrong*. See, for example, the admissions policy of [MIT](http://act.mit.edu/academic-program/admissions/english-proficiency-requirement/). It's possible to get US residence with poor English, so although some universities accept permanent residents without question, having residence does not prove your command of English. You say "For international students, you will be considered as a non-native english speaker, so TOEFL is necessary" - also *wrong*.  Many universities explicitly say "you must do X test only if English is not your first language".

Comment: English is not my first language but I have permanent residency in the US; so I am not a international student. I qualify as domestic student. I did not take TOEFL. Hope the guy who asked the Q understood what was told. I had 720 in my GMAT and over 5 years of work experience. The Universities that I applied to did not ask for TOEFL! You can surely guess which universities I applied for MBA!

Answer (score 10):

Every school words the requirements, if any, for the TOEFL a little differently. For example, [Harvard GSAS](http://www.gsas.harvard.edu/prospective_students/application_instructions_and_information.php):

> Applicants whose native language is other than English and who do not hold the equivalent of a US Bachelor's degree from an institution at which English is the language of instruction must submit scores from the Internet based test (IBT) of the Test of English as a Foreign Language (TOEFL)

A quick look suggests that in general native language and the language of your Bachelor's degree is what matters and not the language of your high school.

Comment: This makes sense, as the graduate institution is primarily interested in knowing whether you are prepared to communicate in English at a collegiate level.